# RatingBar activates function

Tags: android, function, onclick, ratingbar

I'm trying to create RatingBar that activates a function after the user select something on the RatingBar.

This is my RatingBar XML code:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:onClick="sendRank"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And this is how I declared my Java sendRank function:

```
public void sendRank(View view)
```

Maybe there should not be View view like I do in buttons?
Can someone give me hand here?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rater than calling a method from your XML (not even sure the RatingBar will catch the event anyway) I would strongly advise you to have a look at the RatingBar interface that let's you listen to the rating being changed.

Here is the link from the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.html)

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

`RatingBar` has in interface to handle that action called `OnRatingBarChangeListener`. I'd suggest you implement that in your activity rather than the OnClick interface.

You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener.html)